# How to edit/delete Post content on react + firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-router

So I’ve spent the last few weeks learning react and now I’m trying to do so with firebase.

Right now, I am trying to make it possible to edit and delete a blog post. I’ve made a few similar things over the last few weeks with express, rails etc so I thought I got a pretty good handle on it so right now I’m trying to compare and know the differences between them.

Most of the functions have been easily refactored to work with what I’m doing now so I’m not sure exactly how to tweak this one to work here or if it won’t work at all which would then turn to how do I properly do it here.

The original code I used last time that I tried to edit for this was:

```
    getInitialState(){
    return {editable: false} 

},
    handleEdit(){
        if( this.state.editable){
            var title = this.refs.title.value;
            var article= this.refs.article.value;
            var id = this.props.post.id;
            var post = {id: id, title: title, article: article};
            this.props.handleUpdate(post);
         } 
        this.setState({editable: !this.state.editable})
},

render: function(){
    var title= this.state.editable? <input className= "form-control" type='text' ref='title' defaultValue={this.props.post.title}/>:
                                    <h3>{this.props.post.title}</h3>;
    var article= this.state.editable ? <input className= "form-control" type='text' ref='article' name="logEntryEdit" defaultValue={this.props.post.article}/>: 
                                        <p className="postText">{this.props.post.article}</p>;

        return(
            <div >
                <div className="text-center postTitle">
                    {title}
                </div>
                <hr/>
                <br/>
                <div className="text-center" id="postText">
                    {article}
                </div>
                <br/>
                <hr/>
                <button className="btn btn-danger delete-button" onClick={this.props.handleDelete}>Delete</button>
                <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleEdit}>{this.state.editable ? 'Submit' : 'Edit'}</button>

            </div>
        )
```

Naturally I edited the item names and such. How I set up my edit page was by first passing the selected post via the id that firebase generates into a single view page and then pass it in into the edit page. The delete should be from that view page as well.

This is the edit where I tried to put in the above function:

```
      constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state =  {
      title: '',
      body: '',
      post:{},

  };
}


  componentDidMount(){
    database.ref(`posts/${this.props.match.params.postId}`) 
    .on('value', snapshot => {
          this.setState({post: snapshot.val()});
    });
    this.postId= this.props.match.params.postId;
}

 //edit function goes here

      render() {
        return (

                <div className="container">
                  <form onSubmit={this.onHandleUpdate}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                  <input value={this.state.post && this.state.post.title} className="form-control" type="text" name="title" ref="title" placeholder="Title" onChange={this.onInputChange}/>
                </div>
                  <br/>
                <div className="form-group">  
                  <input  value={this.state.post && this.state.post.body} className="form-control" type="text" name="body" ref="body" placeholder="Body" onChange={this.onInputChange}/>
                  <br/>
                </div>
                <button  className="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
              </form>
            </div>

        );
      }
```

When I tried adding it in I also got a

> A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component

It linked me to the docs which I went over as well.

Can you please tell me how to make the original code I had fit in and work for this time or how it is supposed to be done so I can compare and understand the difference?

Answer (score 1):

This error stems from the fact that you are stating that the input fields are updated via a `this.onInputChange`function and yet that function is not defined anywhere. This means there is no way to update the inputs and react does not like that. either define your `this.onInputChange` function or switch to using refs (when you use ref react call that an uncontrolled component).

Comment: If you'd like to read into controlled and uncontrolled form component the official docs is a great place to start https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: Hi Josh! As always youre there to help. 
Would it be possible to set up a chat again for quick explanations? The last one was so helpful

Comment: Sure, but coordinating the time difference between us might take ages.  Taking the time to understand and clearly articulate your problem and open a new question is more helpful to other people who might be struggling with a similar issue. If you don't understand the topic well enough to articulate your problem then you need to learn the fundamentals, through the official docs or an online course or two. Egghead and Frontend masters always have freat react learning the material. Try and make sure the tutorials are recent though, the style of react code you posted in the example is outdated now

Comment: Good to know! I think I have a problem understanding docs and text to be honest and as such I rely on videos and someone explaining to me. 
Also, if youre on right now feel free to join me. I will be in the last chat room.

Comment: join you where?